Went to a house viewing, saw this 'deprecated' open gas pipe off the floor, can it be cut?
Here is a picture of it. There is a obstructed chimney next to it. Agent couldn't advise went we asked. Also this is in England if it matters. 

I don't know what "deprecated" means in this context (maybe it's a Britishism), but perhaps it is for an old gas fireplace?

So was your first question: is there a gas supply? second question: is it still in service?

Most things can be cut/removed.  The question is doing it safety without making a big boom, when it comes to gas.

Don't know what it is, and wouldn't attempt it until that is known, but it looks like it may unscrew.  My guesses;  its gas or water... or (way out there) a door stop?

@RMDman guaranteed it is gas - seen them and removed them, used for gas inserts for fireplaces originally designed for solid fuel which were "updated" when the house or street got a gas supply.

@Solar Mike,  Thanks for the clarification.  Have you seen these in the US?

@RMDman been lucky never had to go to the US... Definitely seen them in the UK though.

The only way to answer that is to trace the pipe to find out if it's disconnected at its other end. If it isn't, you want a gasfitter to do that.

Thanks for the advice. I will definitely get a professional gas fitter/worker to take a look at this on before I take a hacksaw to it!
